# google maps infowindow.content not displayed when using a windows API key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue where my code will work fine if I use a google maps api client key, but not when I use a google maps API key (We need both). In either scenario the map will show properly and we'll get no errors from the google maps server, which means the server is accepting the API key as well. But the actual infowindow content will not show up when the maps API key is provided (with a key of type client, it works fine). I verified that the content (provided below in the msg var) is exactly the same in both cases. There is nothing in the documentation that would indicate any specific difference. Any ideas / suggestions are welcome.

```
    function addpoint(map,x,y,msg,type)
    {
    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
    var mi= getMarkerImage(type);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:LatLng,icon:mi,map: map, title: type});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: '' });
if(msg!="")
{
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
if(last_infowindow){
    last_infowindow.close();
}
infowindow.content = msg;
infowindow.open(map,marker);
last_infowindow = infowindow;
});
}
return LatLng;
}
```

Comment: You probably should ask google support (comes with your client key).  Either that or post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue with a google maps API key.

Comment: Thank you geocodezip. As it happens, the code below had some syntax that is not supported any more (google support provided this answer). I fixed the issue by replacing  below line
infowindow.content = msg;
with
infowindow.setContent(msg);

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, the code had some syntax that is not supported any more (google support provided this information). I fixed the issue by replacing  below line
infowindow.content = msg;
with
infowindow.setContent(msg);